# Can Jawas become residents?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've seen all except one (that I've unlocked so far) of the aliens under Outer Rim in my album appear as residents one time or other in my game, but never seen a Jawa take up residence on one of the floors in the Death Star. Perhaps Jawas only like to stay on sandcrawlers.

Is it possible for Jawas to become residents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I've had one or two. But, they are rare.

I don't have any at the moment to take a picture. They were unskilled and got blown out the airlock.